# Magento store View - Incorrect Size (Attribute) displayed

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I have been fixing this store, based on magento. The main problem of this is that Some of the products display on the store view has incorrect size (which is attribute)

[image]

If you have a look at the picture, on the grid view (list.phtml) the size is US 16/ UK 18 / EUR 48 while on the single view page (view.phtml) it is US 6/ UK 8/ EUR 38.

Have a look at this link

http://www.sequinqueen.com/shop/in-stock.html

I have gone through the code in the view.phtml and appear that the code request the attribute value correctly according to the code below

```
<?php
    $categories =$_product->getCategoryCollection();
    foreach($categories as $_category) {
         $cat_arr[] = $_category['entity_id'];
    }
      if($currentCategoryId==102){
        // CATEGORY ID = 102 is IN-STOCK PRODUCT CATEGORY

         $sizeStock=$_product->getAttributeText('size');

      $day="Ready To Ship";
      $searchfabric=$_product->getSearchfabric();
      $searchcolor=$_product->getSearchcolor();
      $make=$_product->getHandmake();
      $handmake="HandMake";
      $topname=$_product->getTopname();

        <?php $i=$j+1;?>
        <?php $j=$j+1;?>
        <?php if($j<5){?>
          <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==1): ?>
           <ul class="products-grid">
           <?php endif ?>
            <?php if($j==1):?>
            <li class="item first" style="height:434px; background:#FFF;">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("catalog"); ?>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
             <?php echo  $topname; ?>
             <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(162,324); ?>" width="162" height="324" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
             <div style="width:100%;  border-bottom:none; height:80px;">
                 <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                  <?php if($make==1){ echo "<p>".$handmake."</p>";}else{}?>
                  <?php if($currentCategoryId==102){?>
                  <!-- display size -->
                    <p><?php echo $sizeStock; ?></p>
                    <?php } ?>
                  <p>  <?php echo $day; ?></p>
             </div>
            </li>
```

so it came to my thought that it might be something in the store backend, somewhere around attribute modification. 
Here is how the previous developer sorted and arranged the position of the size values I am not sure if this is the cause of problem.

[image]

Anybody is familiar with this problem?
Any answer is appreciated.
thank you in advance.

Comment: your attribute was text box or downdown type?

Comment: It is dropdown type.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reindex product data from "System"->"Index Management" ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
$attribute_value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```